# Excel Formula to jump to specific cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to jump from one cell to a specific cell.

When I enter some data into a cell (say cell A1) and press Enter, I want the document to jump and select another specific cell so that I can enter data there (say jump to cell G1).

I have no code as I don't know how this could be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect the cells you want to jump and unprotect cells A1 and G1. Then when you protect the Sheet, you'll jump from unprotected cell to the next cell unprotected.

You can find it in:

- For cells: Select the cells -> Right click -> Format Cells -> Protection -> Locked
- For sheet: Review -> Protect Sheet -> Unselect locked cells

Answer (score 0):

I think this Macro can Help you

```
 Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim My_col#, My_ro#
If Target.Count = 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Column
      Case 7: My_col = 1: My_ro = Target.Row + 1
      Case 1: My_col = 7: My_ro = Target.Row
      Case Else
      My_col = Target.Column + 1: My_ro = Target.Row
    End Select
Else
  GoTo Leave_Me_Alone_Please
End If
 Cells(My_ro, My_col).Select

Leave_Me_Alone_Please:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```